# How can I show workspace names in unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, workspaces

I have found that the number of workspaces is read from metacitys configuration which also has workspace names. I want to show them.

Comment: By now this question is dated.  Is there still no solution for naming workspaces in unity?

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible with Unity in 11.04.

Comment: The only workable solution I've found (for Ubuntu 14) is to install gnome-session-fallback, log out, and choose metacity as the window manager before completing the log in.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the workspace names feature, but maybe you would like to take a look at the indicator-workspace to have a switch and, also, the number of the workspace you're on:

[OMG! Ubuntu article about indicator-workspace](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/quickly-adjust-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity-with-indicator-workspaces/)

Comment: Already have that, but good you tell other people.

Answer (score -1):

To show work space names, you will need to switch to classic mode by logging out and choosing Ubuntu Classic (No Effects) and log back in.  After this, you need to make sure that your preferences for the workspace switcher have the "Show workspace names in switcher" option checked.

Comment: come on, that's like 'how do I peel a grapefruit? you get a banana.'..